# After Insert the record at index.aspx page redirect to ajax success funtion Asp.net Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, webforms

After Insert the record at index.aspx page redirect to ajax success function and show the message alert("success"); I wrote function `addProject()` to do the task. I didn't get any error. record is added successfully in the database. but `alert("success")` message is not displayed.

**Form design**

```
<form  id="frmProject" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label class="form-label">First Name</label>    
        <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control"  />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" align="left">
        <label class="form-label">Age</label>
        <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
function addProject() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert.aspx',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val()},
        success: function (data) {        
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**insert.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fname = Request.Form["fname"];
    string age = Request.Form["age"];
    string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: perhaps there is some error in `get_all` so the success function fails.

Comment: i removed the get_all function and tried it is doen't work sir.

Comment: console.log i didn't get any message sir

Comment: When the user click the `add` button, the page does a full refresh?

Comment: no without refresh and add the data sir but alert is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the call to `insert.aspx` does not return JSON, but it returns some HTML. jQuery's ajax call with `dataType: 'JSON'` expects that the response of the API call will return a JSON object. If the response cannot be parsed as JSON, the `success` function is not called.

In the `insert.aspx` file, you could have return a JSON object, even an empty one would be sufficient.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="insert.aspx.cs" %>

{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string doSomething(string fname,string age)
    {
      string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age + "')";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      con.Close();
      return "Sucess";
    }
```

And update your ajax call like this

```
function addProject() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Index.aspx/doSomething',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val()},
                success: function (data) {        
                    alert("success");

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: i tried the code which you have posted i got the error on that when i execute the program .string fname = Request.Form["fname"];
            string age = Request.Form["age"];              errros is this an object reference is required for non-static field,method,or property

Comment: i tried the code which you updated. errros is this an object reference is required for non-static field,method,or property .A local variable named 'fname' cannot be declared in this scope.

Comment: Forgot to remove the first two line , Updated my answer check again

Comment: now no error displayed record not added in to the database . and how to call the doSomething function  onePage_Load

Comment: why do you want to call the function on page load , Data will be inserted when you click on Add button, not on page load

Comment: now i understood sir url: 'Index.aspx/doSomething', wrote like this ok. but record not addedd sir.

Comment: there is no error on the debug sir. i think the data didn't pass into Index.aspx/doSomething

Comment: console.error displayed  undefined when click add button

Comment: Check your URL "Index.aspx/doSomething" in post method whether it is valid or not, and try to pass full URL

Comment: console get this error  {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: fname.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n

Comment: Index.aspx/doSomething" in post method how to check whether is it valid or not?

Comment: In your App_Start folder, within your RouteConfig.cs file Comment out the following line
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; or change it to off

Comment: sir i am not using Asp.net mVC i am working on Asp.net

Comment: how to do it in asp.net settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; or change it to off